# How to copy markers and regions between projects in Vegas Pro

Tags: vegas-pro

If I have one or more Vegas Pro projects, sometimes I want to combine them, but just copy and paste on the timeline, even with auto ripple selected, doesn't copy the markers and regions. How can I copy all the clips, markers, and regions from one Vegas Pro project to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little counter-intuitive that Vegas Pro will not copy/paste markers and regions, but this is doable and it's not too difficult.

Here are the following steps to merge `project A` with `project B` into a new `project C`, copying all clips, markers, and regions:

1. Copy all the clips from `project A` timeline.
2. Turn on auto ripple on `project B`. Make sure to select *"All Tracks, Markers, and Regions"* in the drop down.
   [image: Turn on auto ripple in Vegas Pro]
3. Paste the clips from `project A` (copied in step 1) at the beginning of `project B`. All `project B` clips, markers, and regions should have been shifted to the right. All `project A` clips are at the beginning of the timeline on `project B`, but the markers and regions have not been copied.
   [image]
4. Save `project B` as a new file, `project C`.
5. In `project A` go to `View > Window > Edit Details` or type `ALT+6`.
   [image: Open Edit Details in Vegas Pro]
6. In the Edit Details, select Markers or Regions, whichever you want to copy, in the "Show" drop down.
   [image]
7. Select all the items by clicking the empty space on the header row in the first column.
   [image]
8. Type `CTRL+C` to copy the items.
9. In `project C` go to `View > Window > Edit Details` or type `ALT+6`.
10. Select Markers or Regions, whichever you copied from `project A` in steps 6-8.
11. Select the first empty row, then type `CTRL+V`.
    [image]
12. Repeat steps 6-11 as needed, to copy all markers and regions, whichever you haven't done yet.
13. `project C` now contains all clips, markers, and regions from `project A` and `project B`. Don't forget to save your work.
    [image]
14. Optionally, you can re-order all the markers and regions in `project C`. Simply select all the rows by clicking the empty space on the header row in the first column, then type `CTRL+X` then `CTRL+V`.
    [image: Re-order Markers and Regions in Vegas Pro]
    [image]